# reset reducer state when application start while have persist state using redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I am using redux-persist & async storage to persist data  in my react-native-application.
here are  configuration of my redux store

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import {persistReducer, persistStore} from 'redux-persist';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import rootSaga from '../sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
// Middleware: Redux Persist Config
const persistConfig = {
  // Root
  key: 'root',
  // Storage Method (React Native)
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  // Whitelist (Save Specific Reducers)
  whitelist: ['authReducer',],
  // Blacklist (Don't Save Specific Reducers)
  blacklist: [''],
};
// Middleware: Redux Persist Persisted Reducer
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
// Redux: Store
const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
);
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
// Middleware: Redux Persist Persister
let persistor = persistStore(store);
// Exports
export {store, persistor};
```

when i make request to server, i use three type of action dispatch like

```
LOGIN_REQUEST
LOGIN_SUCCESS
LOGIN_FAILURE
```

and dispatch action on request **LOGIN_REQUEST** ( set loading state to true for loading animation & disable login button ), on  successful request **LOGIN_SUCCESS** action is dispatch and **LOGIN_FAILURE** when request fails (and set loading state to false)
here are the reducers

```
...
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        loading : false
      };
    }
    case LOGIN_REQUEST: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    }
    case LOGIN_FAILURE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
      };
    }
...
```

loading animations works good this way.
Problem comes if app closes while request is in progress, and loading state is still true because no LOGIN_FAILURE OR LOGIN_SUCCESS action is dispatched,
next time when app opens there is loading state true and loading animations appears
i looked into some solution like update state on auto dispatched action on start **persist/REHYDRATE** like

```
...
    case "persist/REHYDRATE": {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading : false
      };
    }
...
```

OR

blacklist state like **reducerName.loading** like

```
...
storage: AsyncStorage,
// Whitelist (Save Specific Reducers)
whitelist: ['authReducer',],
// Blacklist (Don't Save Specific Reducers)
blacklist: ['authReducer.loading'],
...
```

is there any better way to tackle this situation
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `AppState` to check for that and disable loading.

```
import {AppState} from 'react-native';

useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, []);

  const _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (appState.current === 'active' && nextAppState.match(/inactive|background/)) {
      //check if loading is true, set is to false if it is
    }

    appState.current = nextAppState;
    setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , it was really helpful.